# When setting vary headers on Ajax response the response is not delivered from the cache

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, browser, browser-cache

I am running into some issues with caching ajax responses.

I managed to get a small test case that reproduces the problem I have.

I tested this in both Firefox 44.0.2, Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m, Opera 35.0.2066.92 and Edge 25.10586.0.0

#### My index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core-compat.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Call1 = new Request({
            url: 'Ajax.php',
            onSuccess: function(){

                setTimeout(function(){

                    var Call2 = new Request({
                        url: 'Ajax.php'
                    });

                    Call2.setHeader('Accept-Language', 'fr-FR');
                    Call2.get();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        Call1.setHeader('Accept-Language', 'en-GB');
        Call1.get();
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

#### My Ajax.php

```php
<?php

header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');
header('Expires: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s T', time() + 3600));
header('Last-Modified: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s T', time()));
header('Vary: Accept-Language');

$headers = getallheaders();

echo $headers['Accept-Language'];
```

#### The problem

These ajax responses are not cached between page visits. They will always hit the Ajax.php, not even sending the `if-modified-since` header.

#### However

When I change the requested `Accept-Language` headers to the same language, it will cache the requests between page visits. So it doesn't seem to be that it won't work at all.

And when I do have different `Accept-Language` headers but don't send the Vary header back, it also caches the responses. But then the cached response is always the first one, because it doesn't take into account the `Accept-Language` header when caching.

Does anyone know if this is a browser issue or if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know pressing F5 also re-requests ajax requests, pressing enter in the url bar doesn't.